# How to disconnect a MutationObserver from inside its callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback, mutation-observers

I'm using `MutationObserver` to wait for the creation of an element on the page, and then adding a button on it (with `init` function).

I only need to add one button but mutations keep happening after this.
I would like to `disconnect()` the observer after having added this button.

I tried something like this:

```
function detect_node_for_buttons(mutations){
    var selector = 'div[class="_2o3t fixed_elem"]';
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation){
        var element =   $(document).find(selector);
        if (element){
            init();
            observer.disconnect();
            return;
        }
        if (!mutation.addedNodes) return;
        for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++){
            if (mutation.addedNodes[i].matches(selector)){
                init();
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        }
    });
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations){
    detect_node_for_buttons(mutations);
});
```

But it didn't work (Perhaps because `observer` isn't yet defined when I call `observer.disconnect()` in `detect_node_for_buttons()`)?

How could I do it?

Comment: Are you saying `detect_node_for_buttons` is triggered again, or `init` is triggered again? `.disconnect` will stop `detect_node_for_buttons` from running, but if there were multiple items in `mutations` or `.addedNodes` then you'll still keep looping over them.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm waiting for the creation of a single element.
but the mutationobserver (and therefore detect_node_for_buttons) is still triggered that's right. I just need to execute it once.
Now I think it's dirty and I would like to "clean" the mutationobserver after the function execution.

Answer (score 11):

Callback function in `MutationObserver` is called with two arguments: mutations array and observer object itself. Because of how you wrote the code `detect_node_for_buttons` never gets observer object. This will do the trick:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(detect_node_for_buttons);
```

You also have to add this argument to function declaration:

```
function detect_node_for_buttons(mutations, observer){ ... }
```