# Disconnect Mutation Observer from Callback Function

Tags: javascript, disconnect, mutation-observers

How can I disconnect my mutation observer from its callback function? The changes are being observed as they should, but I would like to disconnect the observer after the first change. Since the observer variable is out of scope, it's not disconnecting as it should. How can I pass the observer variable to the callback function so the code will work?

```js
function mutate(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if ( mutation.type === 'characterData' ) {
      console.log('1st change.');
      observer.disconnect(); // Should disconnect here but observer variable is not defined.
    }
    else if ( mutation.type === 'childList' ) {
      console.log('2nd change. This should not trigger after being disconnected.');
    }
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('div#mainContainer p').innerHTML = 'Some other text.';
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('div#mainContainer').append('<div class="insertedDiv">New div!<//div>');
  }, 4000);

  var targetOne = document.querySelector('div#mainContainer');
  var observer = new MutationObserver( mutate );
  var config = { attributes: true, characterData: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

  observer.observe(targetOne, config);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MutationObserver disconnect() call inside callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354710/mutationobserver-disconnect-call-inside-callback-function)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest way would be to adjust your callback

```
function mutate(mutations) {
```

to

```
function mutate(mutations, observer) {
```

because the observer instance associated with the mutations is automatically passed as the second parameter to the mutation handler function.

Then you can call `observer.disconnect()` at whichever time you need it.

Comment: Yes, but then how would you pass the observer variable as an argument to mutate()? Could you elaborate your code so I cant test it? I'm interested to see how your code would work.

Comment: You don't have to, `MutationObserver` automatically passes it, the same way it passes `mutations`.

Comment: How is it that JS is able to do this? I've never known a programming language that automatically passes arguments for you. Does this special feature have a name in JS?

Comment: @guest271314 I tried loganfsmyth's approach and yes, it does work. I'm just trying to understand why it works to actually learn something about JS.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Was erroneously still including `document.observer` when tried.

Comment: @GTSJoe Disregard previous comment. loganfsmyth is correct. Was incorrect, here. _"callback
The function which will be called on each DOM mutation. The observer will call this function with two arguments. The first is an array of objects, each of type MutationRecord. The second is this MutationObserver instance."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: You can also use `this.disconnect()` in the callback because it's automatically bound by the API.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Can we pass custom parameters (like a string data) to the `mutate()` function? If so, how can we do it?

Comment: @UnahD Rather than commenting on existing questions, it would be best to create a new question, and spell out what you're actually trying to do with that data.