# How do I disconnect the mutationObserver from inside another function?

Tags: javascript

```
        function observeMutations(object){
        // Select the node that will be observed for mutations

        var targetNode = object
        console.log(targetNode)

        // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
        var config = { attributes: true, childList: true };

        // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
        var callback = function(mutationsList) {
            console.log(mutationsList)
            for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
                if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
                    console.log(mutation)
                    console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
                }
                else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
                    console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
                }
            }
        };

        // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
        var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

        // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
        observer.observe(targetNode, config);

    }
```

I'm running this function on dom elements inside other functions, the problem is it runs more than once on the same dom elements when I execute the function. How do I disconnect it or not run it more than once in each dom element?

I want to disable it from outside the function and not from the inside.

Comment: You need access to `observer`. I would have `observeMutations` return `observer`, but you could just make `observer` a higher scoped `var`, outside and above `observeMutations`. Of course, you would use the return value of `observeMutations` and `.disconnect()` that.

Comment: That worked out, cant highlight your comment for some reason.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32354710/3966682